# Firebase Email signup without Firebase dynamic links

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I‘m wondering if it is possible to use the functionality of firebase magic links completely without firebase dynamic links but rather with my own universal/app links. So basically creating a token, sending it via email and signing the user up/logging the user in with that token.

Since dynamic links are deprecated I don’t want to rely on them in a new app.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Not yet, but we're working on it. From the Firebase FAQ on the Dynamic Links deprecation:

> **I only use Dynamic links for Firebase Authentication, will email link authentication in Firebase Authentication continue to work?**
>
> Yes, your email link authentication using Firebase Authentication will continue to work.
>
> Firebase Authentication currently uses Firebase Dynamic Links to customize Authentication links, but we will provide an update to ensure that this functionality continues working after the Firebase Dynamic Links service is shut down.
>
> Note that this continuation of functionality is separate from using Firebase Dynamic Links for the primary use cases of store and web routing, deferred and regular deep-linking, which will be deprecated according to the migration timeline shared above.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! So would you safely recommend using it in a new app as well?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-limits here on Stack Overflow. But if your question is whether Firebase's email-link sign-in flow will continue to work after the Dynamic Linking product is sunset, then the FAQ answers that: yes, Firebase ensures that this functionality continues working after the Firebase Dynamic Links service is shut down.